How to configure a different project for spring cloud trace?
I am trying to gcp cloud tracing, but I get following:
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Cloud Trace API has not been used in project ProjectA before or it is disabled.

Indeed for ProjectA tracing is not enabled. But the workload is running in another project ProjectB. How can I configure cloud tracing to use ProjectB?
I already tried by adding to my application.properties as defined in https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gcp/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/:
spring.cloud.gcp.trace.project-id="ProjectB"
But this gets not picked up and I get the same error.
build dependencies:
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:5.1.2")
        mavenBom(org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES)
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-context")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging")
    implementation("net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:7.4")
    runtimeOnly("com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-trace")
    runtimeOnly("com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging")
}

